# Using Salesforce Extension Pack in Visual studio professional

Tags: salesforcedx, ide, visualstudiocode

We purchased Visual studio Professional edition recently, for another project. Before this we have been using visual studio code and the Salesforce Extension Pack to code in Salesforce.
Now we want to use the extension pack in our new IDE Visual studio professional. (not code)

We tried to research online to find out how, but we came up short.
Does anyone have experience with this, or know of any other package that does the same?

we would really appreciate the help. It would be great to have all the coding in one IDE.

Best

Comment: Don't think there's a Visual studio professional supported extension for Salesforce. vscode and intelli-j are the most popular ones, out of which vscode is free.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Raul. :) It would have been nice if there was.